# Sorting PHP values based on custom criteria

Tags: php, sorting

I'm trying to sort some data based on four possible values, these are the values and order I'd like them...

GK, DF, MF, FW

How do i amend the current sort function below? I've read about 10 different articles and queries and cant figure it out :(

```
$sort = $_REQUEST['sort'];
if(!isset($sort))
{
    $sort = 'pos';
}
```

Comment: You should add an example of what kind of input you are expecting and how you want it to be at output.

Comment: Look up PHP' `usort()` function.

Comment: Sorry, it's basically a page of football players that pulls their different information, position (pos), name, goals, assists etc, it currently sorts by position in alphabetical order but i want it to do it in that specific order. I'm a complete newb so if someone can point me into the right direction as to what other snippets you need  i can post it? the document is quite large

Answer (score 0):

Ok it is a bit minimal on info.. but lets say that your example is a string.

```
$sort = $_REQUEST['sort'];
$sort = 'GK, DF, MF, FW'; // my assumption

if(!isset($sort))
{
  $arr  = explode(', ',$sort);
  $arr2 = array();
  if( in_array('GK',$arr) ) { $arr2[] = 'GK'; }
  if( in_array('DF',$arr) ) { $arr2[] = 'DF'; }
  if( in_array('MF',$arr) ) { $arr2[] = 'MF'; }
  if( in_array('FN',$arr) ) { $arr2[] = 'FN'; }
  $sort = implode(', ',$arr2); 
}
```

It is ugly, but it does the job.. and for 4 possible values..

Comment: Sorry, it's basically a page of football players that pulls their different information, position (pos), name, goals, assists etc, it currently sorts by position in alphabetical order but i want it to do it in that specific order. I'm a complete newb so if someone can point me into the right direction as to what other snippets you need i can post it? the document is quite large

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your using a database query...you can do something like

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY GK, DF, MF, FW
```